# How to calculate byte as 16 bits in Java

Tags: java, android, byte

I have a value of 2 bytes. 9C 80
Among them
2 bits in the first byte are the mode values ​​as shown in the picture below,
The next 12bit is the number of steps.

This way, you have a total of 2 bytes.

But I don't know how to calculate it in 16 bits.

The result of extracting 12 bits using 9C 80 bytes is 114.

This is wrong.
The correct answer is 39 steps.
39 steps

Can it come out of the 12bit of the 9C 80?

Help.

Below is the bit position of the byte values ​​passed from c.

```c
struct ble_sync_sport_item
{
     uint16_t mode : 2;
     uint16_t sport_count : 12;
     uint16_t active_time : 4;
     uint16_t calories : 10;
     uint16_t distance : 12;
};
```

This is the android code I made to calculate the byte value.

```
private int bytesToInt(byte[] bytes , String value) {
        int binaryToDecimal = 0;
        int binaryToDecimal2 = 0;
        int binaryToDecimal3 = 0;
        int result = 0;
        String s1 = "";
        String s2 = "";
        String s3 = "";
        byteLog("5bytes ",bytes);
        switch (value) {
            case "ACT_STEP":
                s1 = String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(bytes[0] & 0xFF)).replace(' ', '0');
                s2 = String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(bytes[1] & 0xFF)).replace(' ', '0');
                Log.d("FASDF ", "s1 == " + s1 + " s2 = " + s2 );
                s1 = s1.substring(2, 8).concat(s2.substring(0,2));
                s2 = s2.substring(2, 8).concat("00");
                Log.d("FASDF ", "s1 == " + s1 + " s2 = " + s2 );
                binaryToDecimal = Integer.parseInt(s1, 2);
                binaryToDecimal2 = Integer.parseInt(s2, 2);
                result = (int) ((int) binaryToDecimal) + ((int) binaryToDecimal2 << 8);
                Log.d(tag,"result_step =  " + result);
                break;
```

This is the logarithm of the result I calculated.
39 should come out
114 came out.

As the result
The mode value of binary number 10 and
I want to get the sprot_count value of 100111 binary.

D/FASDF: s1 == 10011100 = 0x9C ,, s2 = 10000000 = 0x80
D/SevenHL5ConnectSync: result_step =  114

Comment: Just post the code there. Don't post an image of it. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for help.

Comment: What is a value of five bytes? If you have five bytes then do you have an array of five bytes? Please post the value of those bytes in hexadecimal notation.

Comment: 2+12=14bit!=5byte.

Comment: Start with showing what you have. Then tell what you wanna achief. Then post code where you try to do it.

Comment: Now that you posted code you should better tell what you wanna calculate using this five bytes. Tell first what the result should be. Then tell what you get as result. The function name suggests that you wanna convert five bytes to an integer. But an integer is four bytes. Tell the hexadecimal value of how you wanna be those four bytes.

Comment: It is pretty unclear what you wanna calculate. It looks you are using only the first two bytes.

Answer (score 0):

This could be an issue with bit order in the byte. Please check Big Endian vs Little Endian mode. The result you're getting 114 (1110010) is just the opposite of 39 (0100111) that is a reverse order in the bit.

Comment: 0xC4  0xC5 use with
You should get 369.
In the way you said
I tried changing it in reverse order, but the result was wrong.